# How To Create Query With Conditional Group By

Tags: mysql

I have table like this :

```
+---------+---------------+
| item_id | status        |
+---------+---------------+
| 1       | active        |
| 1       | sold          |
| 1       | deleted       |
| 2       | active        |
| 2       | sold          |
| 3       | active        |
+---------+---------------+
```

what I want is simple output like this. But, with one condition. if some item_id already have 'deleted' status, then it wont show again in this query. and all item_id are grouped into single line.

```
+---------+---------------+
| item_id | status        |
+---------+---------------+
| 2       | active        |
| 3       | active        |
+---------+---------------+
```

I tried using : `SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY item_id`, but the result is not as I expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to have a column called `status`, when it could have more than one value.  You can do what you want with `having`:

```
select item_id
from table
group by item_id
having sum(status = 'deleted') = 0;
```

If you want all the statuses the product has, then add `group_concat(distinct status) as statuses` to the `select`